# inserting university logo in a thesis cover page

Tags: thesis, sharelatex

I want to insert my university logo instead the name only in the cover page of the thesis I am using from sharelatex thesis template. I am uploading both the .tex and .cls file here. please suggest me changes to make.
I am also uploading the logo to show. thanks in advance

This is the .tex file

```
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
%% Thesis.tex -- MAIN FILE (the one that you compile with LaTeX)
%% ---------------------------------------------------------------- 

% Set up the document
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{Thesis}  % Use the "Thesis" style, based on the ECS Thesis style by Steve Gunn
\graphicspath{Figures/}  % Location of the graphics files (set up for graphics to be in PDF format)

% Include any extra LaTeX packages required
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  % Use the "Natbib" style for the references in the Bibliography
\usepackage{verbatim}  % Needed for the "comment" environment to make LaTeX comments
\usepackage{vector}  % Allows "\bvec{}" and "\buvec{}" for "blackboard" style bold vectors in maths
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true}  % Colours hyperlinks in blue, but this can be distracting if there are many links.

%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\frontmatter      % Begin Roman style (i, ii, iii, iv...) page numbering

% Set up the Title Page
\title  {Thesis Title}
\authors  {\texorpdfstring
            {\href{your web site or email address}{Author Name}}
            {Author Name}
            }
\addresses  {\groupname\\\deptname\\\univname}  % Do not change this here, instead these must be set in the "Thesis.cls" file, please look through it instead
\date       {\today}
\subject    {}
\keywords   {}

\maketitle
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------

\setstretch{1.3}  % It is better to have smaller font and larger line spacing than the other way round

% Define the page headers using the FancyHdr package and set up for one-sided printing
\fancyhead{}  % Clears all page headers and footers
\rhead{\thepage}  % Sets the right side header to show the page number
\lhead{}  % Clears the left side page header

\pagestyle{fancy}  % Finally, use the "fancy" page style to implement the FancyHdr headers

%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
% Declaration Page required for the Thesis, your institution may give you a different text to place here
\Declaration{

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1em}}  % Add a gap in the Contents, for aesthetics

I, AUTHOR NAME, declare that this thesis titled, `THESIS TITLE' and the work presented in it are my own. I confirm that:

\begin{itemize} 
\item[\tiny{$\blacksquare$}] This work was done wholly or mainly while in candidature for a research degree at this University.

\item[\tiny{$\blacksquare$}] Where any part of this thesis has previously been submitted for a degree or any other qualification at this University or any other institution, this has been clearly stated.

\item[\tiny{$\blacksquare$}] Where I have consulted the published work of others, this is always clearly attributed.

\item[\tiny{$\blacksquare$}] Where I have quoted from the work of others, the source is always given. With the exception of such quotations, this thesis is entirely my own work.

\item[\tiny{$\blacksquare$}] I have acknowledged all main sources of help.

\item[\tiny{$\blacksquare$}] Where the thesis is based on work done by myself jointly with others, I have made clear exactly what was done by others and what I have contributed myself.
\\
\end{itemize}


Signed:\\
\rule[1em]{25em}{0.5pt}  % This prints a line for the signature

Date:\\
\rule[1em]{25em}{0.5pt}  % This prints a line to write the date
}
\clearpage  % Declaration ended, now start a new page

%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
% The "Funny Quote Page"
\pagestyle{empty}  % No headers or footers for the following pages

\null\vfill
% Now comes the "Funny Quote", written in italics
\textit{``Write a funny quote here.''}

\begin{flushright}
If the quote is taken from someone, their name goes here
\end{flushright}

\vfill\vfill\vfill\vfill\vfill\vfill\null
\clearpage  % Funny Quote page ended, start a new page
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------

% The Abstract Page
\addtotoc{Abstract}  % Add the "Abstract" page entry to the Contents
\abstract{
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1em}}  % Add a gap in the Contents, for aesthetics

The Thesis Abstract is written here (and usually kept to just this page). The page is kept centered vertically so can expand into the blank space above the title too\ldots

}

\clearpage  % Abstract ended, start a new page
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------

\setstretch{1.3}  % Reset the line-spacing to 1.3 for body text (if it has changed)

% The Acknowledgements page, for thanking everyone
\acknowledgements{
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1em}}  % Add a gap in the Contents, for aesthetics

The acknowledgements and the people to thank go here, don't forget to include your project advisor\ldots

}
\clearpage  % End of the Acknowledgements
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------

\pagestyle{fancy}  %The page style headers have been "empty" all this time, now use the "fancy" headers as defined before to bring them back


%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\lhead{\emph{Contents}}  % Set the left side page header to "Contents"
\tableofcontents  % Write out the Table of Contents

%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\lhead{\emph{List of Figures}}  % Set the left side page header to "List if Figures"
\listoffigures  % Write out the List of Figures

%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\lhead{\emph{List of Tables}}  % Set the left side page header to "List of Tables"
\listoftables  % Write out the List of Tables

%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\setstretch{1.5}  % Set the line spacing to 1.5, this makes the following tables easier to read
\clearpage  % Start a new page
\lhead{\emph{Abbreviations}}  % Set the left side page header to "Abbreviations"
\listofsymbols{ll}  % Include a list of Abbreviations (a table of two columns)
{
% \textbf{Acronym} & \textbf{W}hat (it) \textbf{S}tands \textbf{F}or \\
\textbf{LAH} & \textbf{L}ist \textbf{A}bbreviations \textbf{H}ere \\

}

%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\clearpage  % Start a new page
\lhead{\emph{Physical Constants}}  % Set the left side page header to "Physical Constants"
\listofconstants{lrcl}  % Include a list of Physical Constants (a four column table)
{
% Constant Name & Symbol & = & Constant Value (with units) \\
Speed of Light & $c$ & $=$ & $2.997\ 924\ 58\times10^{8}\ \mbox{ms}^{-\mbox{s}}$ (exact)\\

}

%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\clearpage  %Start a new page
\lhead{\emph{Symbols}}  % Set the left side page header to "Symbols"
\listofnomenclature{lll}  % Include a list of Symbols (a three column table)
{
% symbol & name & unit \\
$a$ & distance & m \\
$P$ & power & W (Js$^{-1}$) \\
& & \\ % Gap to separate the Roman symbols from the Greek
$\omega$ & angular frequency & rads$^{-1}$ \\
}
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
% End of the pre-able, contents and lists of things
% Begin the Dedication page

\setstretch{1.3}  % Return the line spacing back to 1.3

\pagestyle{empty}  % Page style needs to be empty for this page
\dedicatory{For/Dedicated to/To my\ldots}

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{2em}}  % Add a gap in the Contents, for aesthetics


%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\mainmatter   % Begin normal, numeric (1,2,3...) page numbering
\pagestyle{fancy}  % Return the page headers back to the "fancy" style

% Include the chapters of the thesis, as separate files
% Just uncomment the lines as you write the chapters

\input{Chapters/Chapter1} % Introduction

%\input{Chapters/Chapter2} % Background Theory 

%\input{Chapters/Chapter3} % Experimental Setup

%\input{Chapters/Chapter4} % Experiment 1

%\input{Chapters/Chapter5} % Experiment 2

%\input{Chapters/Chapter6} % Results and Discussion

%\input{Chapters/Chapter7} % Conclusion

%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
% Now begin the Appendices, including them as separate files

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{2em}} % Add a gap in the Contents, for aesthetics

\appendix % Cue to tell LaTeX that the following 'chapters' are Appendices

\input{Appendices/AppendixA}    % Appendix Title

%\input{Appendices/AppendixB} % Appendix Title

%\input{Appendices/AppendixC} % Appendix Title

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{2em}}  % Add a gap in the Contents, for aesthetics
\backmatter

%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\label{Bibliography}
\lhead{\emph{Bibliography}}  % Change the left side page header to "Bibliography"
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}  % Use the "unsrtnat" BibTeX style for formatting the Bibliography
\bibliography{Bibliography}  % The references (bibliography) information are stored in the file named "Bibliography.bib"

\end{document}  % The End
```

and this is the .cls file

```
%%
%% This is file `Thesis.cls', based on 'ECSthesis.cls', by Steve R. Gunn
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% Created by Steve R. Gunn, modified by Sunil Patel: www.sunilpatel.co.uk

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{Thesis}
              [2007/22/02 v1.0
   LaTeX document class]
\def\baseclass{book}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\baseclass}}
\def\@checkoptions#1#2{
  \edef\@curroptions{\@ptionlist{\@currname.\@currext}}
  \@tempswafalse
  \@tfor\@this:=#2\do{
    \@expandtwoargs\in@{,\@this,}{,\@curroptions,}
    \ifin@ \@tempswatrue \@break@tfor \fi}
  \let\@this\@empty
  \if@tempswa \else \PassOptionsToClass{#1}{\baseclass}\fi
}
\@checkoptions{11pt}{{10pt}{11pt}{12pt}}
\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper}{\baseclass}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{\baseclass}
\newcommand\bhrule{\typeout{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}}

\newcommand\Declaration[1]{
\btypeout{Declaration of Authorship}
\addtotoc{Declaration of Authorship}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\null\vfil
%\vskip 60\p@
\begin{center}{\huge\bf Declaration of Authorship\par}\end{center}
%\vskip 60\p@
{\normalsize #1}
\vfil\vfil\null
%\cleardoublepage
}

\newcommand\btypeout[1]{\bhrule\typeout{\space #1}\bhrule}
\def\today{\ifcase\month\or
  January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
  July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi
  \space \number\year}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{2.0ex plus0.5ex minus0.2ex}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\setmarginsrb           { 1.5in}  % left margin
                        { 0.6in}  % top margin
                        { 1.0in}  % right margin
                        { 0.8in}  % bottom margin
                        {  20pt}  % head height
                        {0.25in}  % head sep
                        {   9pt}  % foot height
                        { 0.3in}  % foot sep
\raggedbottom
\setlength{\topskip}{1\topskip \@plus 5\p@}
\doublehyphendemerits=10000       % No consecutive line hyphens.
\brokenpenalty=10000              % No broken words across columns/pages.
\widowpenalty=9999                % Almost no widows at bottom of page.
\clubpenalty=9999                 % Almost no orphans at top of page.
\interfootnotelinepenalty=9999    % Almost never break footnotes.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead[\rm\thepage]{\fancyplain{}{\sl{\rightmark}}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\sl{\leftmark}}]{\rm\thepage}
\chead{}\lfoot{}\rfoot{}\cfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\btypeout{\thechapter\space #1}\markboth{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{}
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,amsthm,xspace}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\usepackage[centerlast,small,sc]{caption}
\setlength{\captionmargin}{20pt}
\newcommand{\fref}[1]{Figure~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\tref}[1]{Table~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\eref}[1]{Equation~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\cref}[1]{Chapter~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\sref}[1]{Section~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\aref}[1]{Appendix~\ref{#1}}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.85}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{.85}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.1}
\renewcommand{\dbltopfraction}{.85}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.75}
\renewcommand{\dblfloatpagefraction}{.75}
\setcounter{topnumber}{9}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{9}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{20}
\setcounter{dbltopnumber}{9}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[scriptsize]{subfigure}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstpatch}
\lstset{captionpos=b,
        frame=tb,
        basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
        showstringspaces=false,
        keepspaces=true}
\lstdefinestyle{matlab} {
        language=Matlab,
        keywordstyle=\color{blue},
        commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.13,0.55,0.13}\em,
        stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.7,0,0} }
\usepackage[pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=true,
   bookmarksopenlevel=0,bookmarksnumbered=true,hypertexnames=false,
   colorlinks,linkcolor={blue},citecolor={blue},urlcolor={red},
   pdfstartview={FitV},unicode,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{
   \let\\\space
}
\newcommand*{\supervisor}[1]{\def\supname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\examiner}[1]{\def\examname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\degree}[1]{\def\degreename{#1}}
\newcommand*{\authors}[1]{\def\authornames{#1}}
\newcommand*{\addresses}[1]{\def\addressnames{#1}}
\newcommand*{\university}[1]{\def\univname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\UNIVERSITY}[1]{\def\UNIVNAME{#1}}
\newcommand*{\department}[1]{\def\deptname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\DEPARTMENT}[1]{\def\DEPTNAME{#1}}
\newcommand*{\group}[1]{\def\groupname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\GROUP}[1]{\def\GROUPNAME{#1}}
\newcommand*{\faculty}[1]{\def\facname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\FACULTY}[1]{\def\FACNAME{#1}}
\newcommand*{\subject}[1]{\def\subjectname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\keywords}[1]{\def\keywordnames{#1}}
\supervisor  {}
\examiner    {}
\degree      {}
\authors     {}
\university  {\texorpdfstring{\href{University Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {University Name}}
                {University Name}}
\UNIVERSITY  {\texorpdfstring{\href{University Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {UNIVERSITY NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
                {UNIVERSITY NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
\department  {\texorpdfstring{\href{Department or School Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {Department or School Name}}
                {Department or School Name}}
\DEPARTMENT  {\texorpdfstring{\href{Department or School Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {DEPARTMENT OR SCHOOL NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
                {DEPARTMENT OR SCHOOL NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
\group       {\texorpdfstring{\href{Research Group Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {Research Group Name}}
                {Research Group Name}}
\GROUP       {\texorpdfstring{\href{Research Group Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {RESEARCH GROUP NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
                {RESEARCH GROUP NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
\faculty     {\texorpdfstring{\href{Faculty Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {Faculty Name}}
                {Faculty Name}}
\FACULTY     {\texorpdfstring{\href{Faculty Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {FACULTY NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
                {FACULTY NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
\addresses   {}
\subject     {}
\keywords    {}
\renewcommand\maketitle{
  \btypeout{Title Page}
  \hypersetup{pdftitle={\@title}}
  \hypersetup{pdfsubject=\subjectname}
  \hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authornames}
  \hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \let\footnotesize\small
    \let\footnoterule\relax
    \let \footnote \thanks
    \setcounter{footnote}{0}
    \null\vfil
    \vskip 60\p@
    \begin{center}
      \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
      {\large\textbf{\UNIVNAME}\par}
      \vfill
      {\huge \bf \@title \par}
      \vfill
      {\LARGE by \par}
      \smallskip
      {\LARGE \authornames \par}
      \vfill
      {\large A thesis submitted in partial fulfillment for the \par}
      {\large degree of Doctor of Philosophy \par}
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      {\large in the \par}
      {\large \facname \par}
      {\large \deptname \par}
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      {\Large \@date \par}
      \bigskip
    \end{center}
    \par
    \@thanks
    \vfil\null
  \end{titlepage}
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
  \cleardoublepage
}
\newenvironment{abstract}
{
  \btypeout{Abstract Page}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \null\vfil
  \begin{center}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    {\normalsize \UNIVNAME \par}
    \bigskip
    {\huge{\textit{Abstract}} \par}
    \bigskip
    {\normalsize \facname \par}
    {\normalsize \deptname \par}
    \bigskip
    {\normalsize Doctor of Philosophy\par}
    \bigskip
    {\normalsize\bf \@title \par}
    \medskip
    {\normalsize by \authornames \par}
    \bigskip
  \end{center}
}
{
  \vfil\vfil\vfil\null
  \cleardoublepage
}
\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}
\newcounter{dummy}
\newcommand\addtotoc[1]{
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{
\btypeout{Table of Contents}
\begin{spacing}{1}{
    \setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
    \@starttoc{toc}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
   \cleardoublepage
}\end{spacing}
}
\renewcommand\listoffigures{
\btypeout{List of Figures}
\addtotoc{List of Figures}
\begin{spacing}{1}{
    \setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listfigurename
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}
              {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}}
    \@starttoc{lof}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    \cleardoublepage
}\end{spacing}
}
\renewcommand\listoftables{
\btypeout{List of Tables}
\addtotoc{List of Tables}
\begin{spacing}{1}{
    \setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listtablename
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listtablename}{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}}
    \@starttoc{lot}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    \cleardoublepage
}\end{spacing}
}
\newcommand\listsymbolname{Abbreviations}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofsymbols[2]{
\btypeout{\listsymbolname}
\addtotoc{\listsymbolname}
    \chapter*{\listsymbolname
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listsymbolname}{\MakeUppercase\listsymbolname}}
\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
    \cleardoublepage
}
\newcommand\listconstants{Physical Constants}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofconstants[2]{
\btypeout{\listconstants}
\addtotoc{\listconstants}
    \chapter*{\listconstants
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listconstants}{\MakeUppercase\listconstants}}
\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
    \cleardoublepage
}
\newcommand\listnomenclature{Symbols}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofnomenclature[2]{
\btypeout{\listnomenclature}
\addtotoc{\listnomenclature}
    \chapter*{\listnomenclature
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listnomenclature}{\MakeUppercase\listnomenclature}}
\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
    \cleardoublepage
}
\newcommand\acknowledgements[1]{
\btypeout{Acknowledgements}
\addtotoc{Acknowledgements}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\begin{center}{\huge{\textit{Acknowledgements}} \par}\end{center}
{\normalsize #1}
\vfil\vfil\null

}
\newcommand\dedicatory[1]{
\btypeout{Dedicatory}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\null\vfil
\vskip 60\p@
\begin{center}{\Large \sl #1}\end{center}
\vfil\null
\cleardoublepage
}
\renewcommand\backmatter{
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \addtotoc{\bibname}
  \btypeout{\bibname}
  \@mainmatterfalse}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `Thesis.cls'.
```

[image: I want to insert this logo]

Comment: First of all you need to upload your university logo in the same directory where you contain your own thesis. Later we'll need to find the place for add it.

Comment: Hi, I have uploaded the logo.png file in the thesis. I need the command and usepackage to insert in the cover page

Comment: Since the `.cls` file uploads the `graphicx` package you don't need to add it again with `usepackage`. You only need to find the titlepage and add the logo with `\includegraphics` in the line you consider it should be placed.

Comment: I want to remove the University name at very first line of the cover page, and insert the logo. When I use '\includegraphics{Logo.png}' it gives me another first page with only the logo, the second page goes for typical thesis coverpage. how do I do this?

Comment: If you really need a different titlapage you can build your own _easily_ using the [titlepage environment](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation).

Comment: sorry, I didnot make you understand, I do not want another coverpage, I just want the university name to be replaced by the logo in the coverpage

Comment: @ignasi, can you please do it for me?

Comment: Note that it should be `\graphicspath{{Figures/}}` with an additional pair of braces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically say you want to replace the name with the logo. Do it.

```
\university{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-1x1}}
```